# jquery / javascript: Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys,
i wrote a little custom animated scroll function...

```
function scroll(selector, animate, viewOffset) {

    pageOffset = selector.offset();
    scrollPos = pageOffset.top - viewOffset;

    if (animate) {

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : scrollPos + 'px'}, {
            duration: 'slow', // how fast we are animating
            easing: 'easeOutQuint', // the type of easing
            complete: function() { }
        });

    } else {
        $('html, body').scrollTop( scrollPos );
    }

}
```

I call it with  `scroll($('#something'), false, 30);`

It actually works, however sometimes it's a little bit buggy and the function doesn't properly work. I always call the scroll() function on a click-event.

The biggest problem I have is that on page load my console tells me the following line.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'top' of null (script.js line 191 which is line 3 in my example above)

Any idea what could cause this error? the scroll() function is not even called on dom-ready or on-load. It's just called on specific click-events.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
pageOffset = $(selector).offset();
```

?

Comment: That depends if the parameter is already a jQuery object or not.  Personally, I always wrap everything with $.() though, so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: The parameter name 'selector' implies that it is a simply selector rather than a jQuery object - you could be right, however to me it looks like it is not a jQuery object, and that does explain the error he is getting.

Comment: it still gets the same error when you try and use scroll() http://jsfiddle.net/ALYpY/

Comment: ok that worked. however am I not already passing a jquery object when i call `scroll($('#something'),...`?

Comment: in the text he says he's passing in `$('#something')`

Comment: @mathiregister - It could be an issue with the readiness of the DOM? Can you post the relevant markup please?

Comment: what do you mean by relevant markup. Than I would have to post my entire page! What do you mean by readiness of my DOM. It's really weird. It works on my frontpage but doesn't work on some subpages. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get same "mysterious errors" with selector mistypes.

Wrap all code in your function with try/catch statement and try to debug it. There are debug tools in almost all major browsers. Set a breakpoint inside catch statement and then your script hit there look at pageOffset and selector variables.

P.S.: PhpStorm has the best debugger for JavaScript a ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have #selector defined on your page?